# Why converting np.nan to int results in huge number?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array like this below:

```
array([['18.0', '11.0', '5.0', ..., '19.0', '18.0', '20.0'],
       ['11.0', '14.0', '15.0', ..., '45.0', '26.0', '20.0'],
       ['1.0', '0.0', '1.0', ..., '3.0', '4.0', '17.0'],
       ...,
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', ..., 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', ..., 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
       ['nan', 'nan', 'nan', ..., 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']],
      dtype='|S230')
```

But converting it to int array makes the np.nan value to be weird values:

```
df[:,4:].astype('float').astype('int')

array([[                  18,                   11,                    5,
        ...,                   19,                   18,
                          20],
       [                  11,                   14,                   15,
        ...,                   45,                   26,
                          20],
       [                   1,                    0,                    1,
        ...,                    3,                    4,
                          17],
       ...,
       [-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        ..., -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        -9223372036854775808],
       [-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        ..., -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        -9223372036854775808],
       [-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        ..., -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808,
        -9223372036854775808]])
```

So how to fix my problem ?

Comment: Your value is not `np.nan` but the string `"nan"`.  What do you expect the result to be when you convert that to an integer?

Comment: replace your 'nan' with np.nan

Comment: @BrenBarn he coerced to `float` first, which I believe should give actual `Nan`.

Comment: Yes, converting the string to float makes the 'nan' to be nan. How to makes the float parts to be int ?

Comment: @yanachen you cannot, that is undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no such thing as an integer `nan`.  `nan` is a float value.

Answer (score 2):

Converting floating-point `Nan` to an integer type is undefined behavior, as far as I know. The number:

```
-9223372036854775808
```

Is the smallest int64, i.e. `-2**63`. Note the same thing happens on my system when I coerce to `int32`:

```
>>> arr
array([['18.0', '11.0', '5.0', 'nan']],
      dtype='<U4')
>>> arr.astype('float').astype(np.int32)
array([[         18,          11,           5, -2147483648]], dtype=int32)
>>> -2**31
-2147483648
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what you expect the result to be. `nan` is of a float type, so converting the string `'nan'` into float is no problem. But there is no definition of converting it to `int` values.

I suggest you handle it differently - first choose what spcific `int` you want all the `nan` values to become (for example 0), and only then convert the whole array to `int`

```
a = np.array(['1','2','3','nan','nan'])
a[a=='nan'] = 0 # this will convert all the nan values to 0, or choose another number
a = a.astype('int')
```

Now `a` is equal to

```
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```